# " at the weekend" vs "at weekends"

Tags: grammar, general-vs-specific

The Longman dictionary of contemporary English lists the following example for the word "weekend"
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/weekend_1

> I never work at the weekend.

However, I think the sentence

> I never work at weekends.

is more appropriate. What am I missing?

Comment: At least in British English, _at the weekend_ can mean 'at weekends in general' as well as 'this coming weekend'.

Comment: Checking Google ngrams to try to gauge idiomaticity is considered basic research on ELU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"At weekends" is not really what one could call "more appropriate", as it does mean the same thing, but it is used more often than "at the weekend": [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+weekend%2Cat+weekends&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Without changing the meaning you can use "on" instead of "at" and you find that "on weekends" is much more often used than any other in AmE: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+weekend%2Con+weekends%2Cat+the+weekend%2Cat+weekends&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20weekends%3B%2Cc0).

This is not so in BrE: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+weekend%2Con+weekends%2Cat+the+weekend%2Cat+weekends&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=29&smoothing=3#)